# Units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}(\omega)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $\omega \not= 1$ is a cube root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, show that the units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ are the elements of modulus 1. Hence, or otherwise, show that $U(\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is cyclic.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin with this question!!

PLease help, Thanks!

Comment: To begin: write down a formula for the elements of ${\Bbb Z}[\omega]$.  Then write down the definition of a unit.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] = \{a+b\omega : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, \omega \not=1\}$
A unit in a ring is an element such that $uu^{-1} = 1$

OKay?

Comment: Not OKay, as David suggested, combine the two statements you just wrote.  What is $(a+b\omega)^{-1}$?  You should be able to make a formula for that.  When is it a member of $\Bbb Z(\omega)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z[}x\mathbb{]}$={a+bω:a,b$\in \mathbb{Z}$, ω≠1 and ω³=1}.

Definition of unit tells us the following:
if u is a unit then there exists v in the ring such that uv=1 and this v is called as inverse of u. It is fact that the inverse of element is unique. If we find all elements whose inverse also in this ring we are done.

Take a+bω$\in \mathbb{Z}$ it is clear that
Now we need to find all a and b that makes this element
in the ring. i.e. the question turns for which a,b$\in \mathbb{Z}$, (a+bω)$^{-1}=\frac{1}{(a+bω )}\in \mathbb{Z[ω]}$

since ω≠1 and $(ω-1)({ω}^{2}-ω-1)=0$, we have $({ω}^{2}-ω-1)=0$ and so we have $(-1-ω)$ instead of ${ω}^{2}$ in the ring and we have $(x+y)^{3}=(x+y)(x^{2}-xy+y^{2})$ so
multiply numerator and denominator of $\frac{1}{(a+bω)}$ by $(a^{2}-ab%
\mathbb{ω}+(b\mathbb{ω )}^{2})$. We have the following:

$\frac{a^{2}-abω+(bω\mathbb{)}^{2}}{(a+bω)(a^{2}-abω+(bω\mathbb{)}^{2})}$=$\frac{a^{2}-abω+(bω\mathbb{)}^{2}}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$=$\frac{a^{2}-abω+b^{2}ω^{2}}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$=$\frac{a^{2}-abω-b^{2}ω-b^{2}}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$=$\frac{a^{2}-b^{2}-ω(ab+b^{2})}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$.

therefore, $\frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$ and $\frac{(ab+b^{2})}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$ has to be integer.

So, we have $\frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$=$\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$=$\frac{(a+b)}{(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$

and similarly,

$\frac{(ab-b^{2})}{a^{3}+b\mathbb{}^{3}}$=$\frac{(b)(a+b)}{(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$=$\frac{(b)}{(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$

to become this expression integer denominator has to be 1. So, lets determine which a and b makes this expression integer namely inverse element in the ring.

$(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})$=1 so $(a^{2}+b^{2})$=$1+(ab)$. since left hand side always 0 or positive, $ab$ has to be greater then or equal to $-1$ then $((a-b)^{2}+ab)=1$ so $((a-b)^{2})=(1-ab)$ since left hand side always 0 or positiv, $ab$ has to be less than or equal to $1$. So we have following inequalities for $ab$;

$-1\leq ab\leq 1$

since a and b are integer we have following possibilities for this inequality

$a=1$,$b=1$ and $a=1$,$b=-1$ and $a=-1$,$b=1$ and $a=-1$,$b=-1$ and $a=0$,$b=1$ and $a=0$,$b=-1$ and $a=1$,$b=0$ and $a=-1$,$b=0$

as a result we have following elements which are the unit of this ring
$1+ω$, $1-ω$, $-1+ω$, $-1-ω$, $ω$, $-ω$, $1$, $-1$

Comment: i found my mistake:
the cases where ab=-1 has to be cancelled bcs we cancelled (a+b)'s from denominators so if ab=-1 than (a+b) will be equal 0. we need to cancel (-1+w) and (1-w) then it will be done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Are there any elements other than $0$ with modulus $< 1$?

[image]

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Can you see what it looks like geometrically?

Comment: Not really no... Sorry I'm rubbish at this stuff

Comment: No, there aren't.